# Problems with re.sub() on UTF-8 content from PGSQL

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I've tried many different things and looked at many SO answers (and stuff from other websites too) and I can't seem to figure this one out. There's a lot of conflicting information out there.

I have some content stored in PostgreSQL, in UTF8 (SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';). I am pulling said content from the DB, then wrapping any "£" signs in a span.

Relevant snippet:

```
for i in range(0, len(results)):
  content = results[i][2].decode('utf8')
  pattern = re.compile(ur'(\u00A3[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?', re.UNICODE)
  content = re.sub(pattern, '<span class="price">\0\1</span>', content)
  app.logger.debug(test)
```

Sample output:

```
DEBUG in **** [****.py:143]:
Prices from only <span class="price"></span> for a framed picture.
```

EDIT: And I'm aware the REGEXP is probably bad.

Comment: If its not matching you wouldn't get output. Are you sure `\0` means capture group 0 (the entire match)? Maybe it should be `\\0` or `$0`. You can try `(\u00A3[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)` and use `\1`.

Comment: Looks like I had to use a raw string (r'') for the second parameter of sub() and \1 was the correct capture group. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [capturing/named group in regex](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) to first check the regex is working with the general caption and then wrapping only what you need or delete exactly what you need:

```
for i in range(0, len(results)):
  pattern = re.compile('[0-9]*(?P<todelete>\W)?')
  todelete = pattern.match(i[0][2]).group('todelete')
  content = todelete.sub("", i[0][2])
```

By the way to pull info from posgresql I recommend [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html) that correctly fetch one or many results in a simple list and respecting general encoding : that should maybe avoid many headaches.